# Encode ids in Rails app

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I am working in a Rails application.
The app has concepts like user can add custom tabs and add custom sections under each tab.
Also user can delete these tabs or sections from frontend.

Right now i am using the actual Tab id / Section id in the delete option like `div id="del_1"`
, so when user clicks this div the id is separated and passed through ajax request for deleting the section or tab.

is showing actual id of a tab/section or any other entities in front end for this kind of operation is correct?

if not how can i encode these data in the html?
i tried using baseencode, but it produces some special characters which i cannot really use in html.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If there isn't some security reason you need to obfuscate the object ids I wouldn't suggest trying to. As far as I'm concerned showing the actual id of an object in the front end is not only correct but makes the entire system easier to understand and develop.

That being said you shouldn't trust what comes from your clients, so if you need a auth/permissions system take a look at [Devise](https://github.com/plataformatec/devise/) or [AuthLogic](https://github.com/binarylogic/authlogic/).